# XSLT: Testing position against concurrent criteria within xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, xpath

Consider the following two xsl:value-of statements using XPath expressions testing the position of a node.

(1) This one, as I understand it, will return the value of the /ChildThree child of a /Parent where three things are independently true of that /Parent - (i) it has a /ChildOne with value "x"; AND (ii) it has a /ChildTwo with value "y"; AND (iii) it is the second or subsequent /Parent within its immediate ancestor:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y'][position()&gt;=2]/ChildThree"/>
```

(2) This one, by contrast, will return the value of the /ChildThree child of a /Parent where that /Parent is the second or subsequent /Parent OF THOSE THAT HAVE BOTH a /ChildOne with value "x" AND a /ChildTwo with value "y":

```
<xsl:value-of select="(Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y'])[position()&gt;=2]/ChildThree"/>
```

So far so good. However, what happens in the following example? Here, I'm trying to get the value of the /ChildThree child of any /Parent for which the first two criteria are concurrently true, but only precede it with a space if the /Parent is the second or subsequent within that subset (i.e., like example (2), above). How can I dictate how the position criterion within the xsl:if statement applies to the criteria in the xsl:for-if statement, when it is not part of the same XPath expression?

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y']">
<xsl:if test="position()&gt;=2">
<xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:value-of select="ChildThree"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Seeing the XML document you are referring to would be immensely helpful in understanding your question, IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two statements (1) and (2) are actually equivalent, and will return the same results.

**position()** is context-sensitive. It will give you the position of the current node within the set of nodes previously selected. So, when you have the expression `Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y']` it is returning a set of nodes where two conditions is true. Doing `Parent[ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y'][position()&gt;=2]` will give the second (or greater) node in this list.

The way you are describing how you think (1) works, would actually look like this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="Parent[position()&gt;=2][ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y']/ChildThree"/>
```

One way to think of it, is to think of every condition in square brackets filtering what has come before.

Try it out on this XML, for example

```
<Parents>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>a</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>b</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>c</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z1</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
   <Parent>
      <ChildOne>x</ChildOne>
      <ChildTwo>y</ChildTwo>
      <ChildThree>z2</ChildThree>
   </Parent>
</Parents>
```

Your statements (1) and (2) both return **z2**, but doing `Parent[position()&gt;=2][ChildOne='x'][ChildTwo='y']/ChildThree` returns **z1**.

What this means is that your **xsl:for-each** should actually give you the results you expect.